# creating username and set password remotely

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ssh

I am running script which generated strong password and takes input as user name and calls
remote script to create username and password .

script goes like this

```
USERNAME=$1

PASS=`cat /dev/urandom|tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-!@#%()+{}$|:?='|fold -w 10 | head -n 1| grep -i '[!@#%()+{}|:$?=]'`

ssh -i /home/ubuntu/test.pem  ubuntu@192.168.10.32 "sudo /bin/bash /root/useradd.sh $USER $PASS "
```

It works fine ,if the password does not contain any extra characte like | , & and $ .

e.g.

```
ssh -i /home/ubuntu/test.pem  ubuntu@192.168.10.32 "sudo /bin/bash /root/useradd.sh testuser1 12345 "
```

it fails with strong password as follows .

```
ssh -i /home/ubuntu/test.pem  ubuntu@192.168.10.32 "sudo /bin/bash /root/useradd.sh testuser1 v|9q4TT8={ "
```

Is there any workaround for this .

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use enclosing `" "` to use strong password, bash will treat any character between `" "` as String.

```
ssh -i /home/ubuntu/test.pem ubuntu@192.168.10.32 "sudo /bin/bash /root/useradd.sh \"$USER\" \"$PASS\" "
```

And don't forget to escape inner quotes. i.e. add like `\"`